# Tkinter ListBox and dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, listbox

Displaying list items in a tkinter listbox looks like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

lst = ["one", "two", "three"]
lstbox = Listbox(root)
lstbox.pack()

for item in lst:
    lstbox.insert(END, item)

root.mainloop()
```

How can I display a dictionary with both its keys and values using a listbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the keys of the dictionary and insert a string comprising the key and its value. You can use `str.format()` to create the string. Here's an example:

```
d = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}

for key in d:
    lstbox.insert(END, '{}: {}'.format(key, d[key]))
```

---

Note that the items will not be in any particular order because dictionaries are unordered. You could sort the keys like this:

```
for key in sorted(d):
    lstbox.insert(END, '{}: {}'.format(key, d[key]))
```